# I need to make a dynamic list / page that shows data from different Sharepoint 2007 document libraries

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

We have several document libraries where users upload reports daily. I have to make a page that shows specific documents (getting them by their filename) from these document libraries with each documents last modified date.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom SharePoint list that contains 2 columns (the filename of the report and the doc lib path).  Create a custom SharePoint webpart to iterate over that custom list, go grab the actual file and show the properties that you want, add this custom webpart to your site page somewhere.

If you want to go further, you can add a custom action that will add / remove the report to / from the custom list and attach it to all those document libraries so user can easily manage which report to show in your custom page.

Comment: so do I need to program a custom webpart? I am totally lost, if so. Is there any alternative?

Comment: You can use SharePoint object model with plain vanilla ASP.NET page and embed that in SharePoint using a Content Editor WebPart if you are not too keen about creating SharePoint custom webpart.

Comment: You don't even need a Content Editor Web Part on a plain ASP.NET page if all you need is to get documents, their names, and the last modified date. A plain application page should suffice (I implemented something similar).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you take a look at existing products like MatchPoint for SharePoint ([www.getmatchpoint.com](http://www.getmatchpoint.com)). It provides WebParts to aggregate documents and other informations.